# Website database not working after launching

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I have launched my website but database is not accessible it shows an error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured

Comment: You have to provide more info about where your database is, how you deployed it and how your app connects to it.

Answer (score 1):

**According to your question there may arise these 3 solution**

1.I think you are acessing from your local database to use to on an online
    website make your database also online and try again to access.

2.If website is local restart your sql server services.

3.Check your connection string weather you have provided the same instance name or not